Derivation of Expected Number of Occurrences in a stochastic Intensity Poisson Process Using Given Axioms
I have a question concerning the expected number of occurrences in a random intensity Poisson process during a specific interval.
Let $N_t(h)$ be a random variable counting the number of events that happen during the interval $(t, t+h)$,
and $R(t)$ be a random variable representing the occurrence rate at time $t$.
Four axioms are provided for the process:
(1) $N_t(0)=0$
(2)${N_t(h), h\geq0}$ has independent increments
(3) $P(N_t(h) = 1) = R(t)h +o(h)$
(4) $P(N_t(h) \geq 2) = o(h)$
Here, the notation $o(h)$ denotes any function such that $\lim_{h\to0}{o(h) \over h}=0 $.
Now, onto my question. In the textbook, I encountered the equation $E[N_t(h)|R(t)] = R(t)h+o(h)$.
My question is twofold:

How can I deduce this equation based on the given axioms?

Can I derive the equation using only axioms (3) and (4), or should axiom (2) also be involved?


In my understanding, if $P(N_t(h) = k) = {h^2 \over k^2}$ (where $k \geq 2$) when $h$ is reasonably small, it satisfies axioms (3) and (4). However, the equation fails as $E[N_t(h)|R(t)]$ diverges to infinity. Therefore, axiom (2) must be considered.
I appreciate any insights or comments on this matter.
